# my code doesn't run some thing wrong about strings, c++

Tags: c++

I was training on solving algorithms, I wrote a code but it won't compile
in (if) I can not check `s[i]=='S'` .

I'm trying to if `s[i]` is S character or not but I don't know where my problem is.

If I can't use this syntax, what could be a solution?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  double v_w=25,v_s=25,d_w=25,d_s=25;
  int n;
  cin>>n;
  string s[]={"WSSS"};

  int i ;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++)
  {
      if( s[i] == "W" )
      {
          v_s += 50;
          d_w = d_w + (v_w/2);
          d_s = d_s + (v_s/2);
          cout<<"1 \n";
      }
      if(s[i]=='W')
      {
          v_w +=50;
          d_w = d_w + (v_w/2);
          d_s = d_s + (v_s/2);
          cout<<"2 \n";
      }
      return 0;
  }

  cout<< d_w<<endl<<d_s;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code, with a debugger?

Comment: `string s[]={"WSSS"};` - array of one `std::string`, typo.

Comment: Some questions are so hilariously poorly written it'd be a shame to edit them.

Comment: Do you really want boths `if`s in there or are you just asking why the second doesn't work?

Comment: `if(s[i] == 'W')` s is an array of strings not just an array of characters so the first element is a string: `if(s[i] == "W")`

Answer (score 4):

`string s[]={"WSSS"};` means an array of `string`s which the first one is `"WSSS"`.

What you need is:

```
std::string s="WSSS";
```

Answer (score 2):

`string s[] = {"Hello"}` is an array of strings (well, of one string).

If you iterate over it, or index into it `s[0]` is "Hello".

***Whereas***

`string s{"Hello"}` is one string, which is made up of characters.

If you iterate over it, or index into it `s[0]`, you will get 'H'.

---

To pre-empt all the other things that are going to go wrong when the string versus character problem is sorted, lets move the `return 0;` from the middle of the for loop.

Then let's think about what happens if the number `n` entered is larger than the length of the string:

```
int n;
cin>>n; //<- no reason to assume this will be s.length (0 or less) or even positive
string s{"WSSS"}; //one string is probably enough

int i ;
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    if( s[i] == 'W' ) //ARGGGGGGG may have gone beyond the end of s
    {
```

In fact, let's just drop that for now and come back to it later. And let's use a range based for loop...

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    double v_w = 25, v_s = 25, d_w = 25, d_s = 25;

    string s{ "WSSS" };

    for (auto && c : s)
    {
        if (c == 'W')
        {
            v_w += 50;
            d_w = d_w + (v_w / 2);
            d_s = d_s + (v_s / 2);
            cout << "2 \n";
        }
    }
    cout << d_w << '\n' << d_s << '\n'; //<- removed endl just because...

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

s is an array of strings in this case it has only element:

```
string s[] = {"WSSS"};
```

so writing `s[2];` // is Undefined behavior

your code will produce a UB if the user enters `n` greater than the number of elements in `s`:

```
n = 4;
for(i = 0; i < n; i++) // s[3] will be used which causes UB
{
    if( s[i] == 'W' ) // s[i] is a string not just a single char
    {
    }
}
```

also as long as s is an array of strings then to check its elements check them as strings not just single chars:

```
if( s[i] == "W" ) // not if( s[i] == 'W' )
```

I think you wanted a single string:

```
string s = {"WSSS"};
```

because maybe you are accustomed to add the subscript operator to character strings:

```
char s[] = {"WSSS"};
```

if so then the condition above is correct:

```
if( s[i] == 'W' )
```